# get content of tag a by explode function

Tags: php, explode

i have content :

```
<a href="/dien-vien/Chris-Pratt">Chris Pratt</a>,<a href="/dien-vien/Vin-Diesel"> Vin Diesel</a>,<a href="/dien-vien/Bradley-Cooper"> Bradley Cooper</a>
```

i want return string: Chris Pratt, Vin Diesel, Bradley Cooper

i try code:

```
$actor = explode(',', $actor[0]);
$count_actor = count($actor);

for ($i=0; $i < $count_actor; $i++) { 
    $actor = explode('">', $actor[$i]);
    $actor = explode('</a>', $actor[1]);
    $actor .= $actor[0].",";
}
```

i only get is : Array,

please everybody help me.

Answer (score 3):

Better parse HTML properly using `DOMDocument` API

```
<?php

$html = '<a href="/dien-vien/Chris-Pratt">Chris Pratt</a>,<a href="/dien-vien/Vin-Diesel"> Vin Diesel</a>,<a href="/dien-vien/Bradley-Cooper"> Bradley Cooper</a>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

$actors = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       array_push($actors, trim($tag->nodeValue));
}

echo implode(',', $actors); // Chris Pratt,Vin Diesel,Bradley Cooper
```